# Maximum call [...] ao tentar abrir dialogo de arquivo

Tags: javascript, input

HTML

```
<div class="send">click<input name="files[]" class="file" type="file"></div>
```

Javascript:

```
$('body').on('click', '.send', function(e) {
     $(document).find('.file').click();
});
```

CSS:

```
 input {
   opacity: 0;
 }
```

ao clicar em "click" é retornado o erro, pois ele detecta clique na div pai e div filha provocando um loop, como resolver? Eu anseio apenas abrir a input file.

ex: https://jsfiddle.net/s5rzjfhn/3/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O problema é que quando fazes `.find('.file').click();` ele vai disparar um evento no elemento pai também, por propagação no DOM.

Tens de juntar um outro auscultador de eventos que pare a propagação do evento ao elemento pai, logo no input.

```
$('body').on('click', '.send_file', function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

#### jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/xsoxrbw0/

Porém a maneira que me parece melhor para fazer isso é sem JavaScript. Usando só um `label` assim:

```
<label class="send normal_send">click
    <input name="files[]" class="send_file" type="file">
</label>
```

#### jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/jzacpz2p/

Comment: Não conhecia essa da `label` testei em meu script mas não funcionou, deve ser por causa que é um icone feito com o `:before`. Obrigado pela solução!!